# Trouble with syntax of adding setTimeout to existing jQuery script

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I want to add a setTimeout to the following code so that there's a short pause before the fadeOut effect executes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#menu li').hover(
        function() {
            $('ul', this).slideDown(50);
        }, 
        function() {
            $('ul', this).fadeOut(100);
        }
    );
});
```

This is what I'm trying, but I'm guessing the syntax must be wrong:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#menu li').hover(
        function() {
            $('ul', this).slideDown(50);
        },
        function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('ul,' this).fadeOut(100);
            });
        }
    );
});
```

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I'm a beginner with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also need to clear the timeout when going over it using [`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.clearTimeout) (in case you hover in/out fast), something like this would work:

```
$(function() {  
  $('#menu li').hover(function() {
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
    $('ul', this).slideDown(50);
  }, function() {
    $.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
      $('ul,' this).fadeOut(100);
    }, this), 400));
  });
});
```

This stores/retrieves the timer ID using [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/), and currently has a 400ms delay, just adjust accordingly.

Comment: Is there an opposite of "this"? Might there be a way to fadeOut all other ul's when the one you're on is on slideDown?

Comment: @Tom - You can use `.not()` for example: `$('#menu li').not(this).find('ul')` to get all other child `<ul>` elements.

Comment: Thanks, Nick. I had to add some classes to differentiate between the different levels of ul's and li's, but that worked for me. Thanks again!

Comment: @Tom - Welcome :) You can also do `$(this).children('ul')` to go one a level down instead of `$('ul', this)`, if that helps any :)

Comment: To clarify, I had to add identifying classes to prevent the 2nd level ul's from disappearing prematurely. Otherwise, they'd disappear as soon as I mouseout from the top level li. $(this).children('ul') doesn't seem to solve that, unless I'm doing it wrong:

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#menu li').hover(function() {
  clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
  $(this).children('ul').slideDown(50);
  $('#menu li').not(this).children('ul').hide();
 }, function() {
  $.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
   $(this).children('ul').fadeOut(100);
  }, this), 500));
 });
});

Answer (score 3):

The meaning of `this` is different within a `setTimeout()`. You need to reference the desired `this` in a variable or get the `ul` first and reference that.

```
var th = this;
setTimeout(function() {
    $('ul', th).fadeOut(100);
});
```

or

```
var $ul = $('ul',this);
setTimeout(function() {
    $ul.fadeOut(100);
});
```

Comment: +1 - Good catch on this, `$.proxy()` is also an alternative here to maintain context.

Comment: @Nick - Thanks. Why do I *always* forget about `$.proxy()`?!